# Outliers chart single chart for many independent variable similar to pairs() function

Tags: r

Problem:

Outliers chart to display outliers in a condensed summary.

Approach:

I am seeking a way to display outliers in a condensed summary, similar to the pairs() function in R. I have a requirement to keep my solution in R markdown to a limited number of pages, so when I create boxplot() with the outlier parameter, I must create 13, 14 charts. This fills the page limit too quickly. So I am seeking for a more condensed approach to display critical outliers for 14 independent predictor variables. I currently use this code:

```
outlier_values <- boxplot.stats(df$income, coef = 3)$out
boxplot(df$income, main="Status ~ Income", boxwex=0.7)
```

But running it 14 times for 14 variables is too many pages. Is there any condense chart approach similar to pairs() that I can get my boxplot() onto a single chart?

Comment: Have you tried `par(mfrow=c(3,5))` ?

Comment: No, good idea, let me try and get back to you

Comment: worked great. thank you. I forgot about par(mfrow...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a grid of plots (like `pairs`) by running `par(mfrow=c(3,5))` prior to making your 14 boxplots.

Comment: thanks...that is what I did from G5W suggestion: par(mfrow=c(3,5))...boxplot()...par(mfrow=c(1,1))